# SQL View Summarizing One Table, Columns Based on Unknown Categories Entered

Tags: sql

I have a table in the form:

```
date / category (string) / count (integer)
--------------------------------------------
7/15      A                   3
7/15      B                   7
7/15      C                   2
7/16      A                   9
7/16      B                   1
7/16      C                   2
```

Basically, for each day, each category will have a count associated with it.

The problem is, I don't necessarily know what these categories will end up being. Say I know they are A, B, and C, but next week, there is a D, E, and F.

And this is the view that I want to build:

```
Date / A  / B  / C / .. (however many categories found) 
---------------------------------------------------------
7/15   3    5    2    3    4
7/16   9    5    9    6    4
...
..
.
```

I usually know enough SQL to get by, but this one is racking my brain. I don't think I am using the right vocabulary when trying to google it, because I'm not finding the answers I am looking for.

Comment: For MSSQL, in this case I would use a PIVOT table with dynamic SQL so you can have a varying number of columns for your categories.

Comment: Alternatively, you could combine the counts into a single column, separated, say, by commas.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, you cannot build a view to do what you would like.  A view has its  columns pre-defined.

You could do one of the following:

1. Create a stored procedure that creates a view every week.  This stored procedure would analyze the data, determine the columns, and then use dynamic SQL to alter the view.
2. Change the definition of what you want and put the values in a single column, separated by commas (or some other character).
3. Predefine a list of acceptable columns, create the view (using pivot, say) and then periodically go through an modify it when new values arise.
4. Do the pivoting at the application layer.  This is particularly easy in Excel.

One big caveat with (1) and (3).  If anything uses the view as "select * from view", you need to be sure that those queries/stored procedures/user defined functions/etc. are recompiled.  Otherwise, they will have the wrong list of columns (this may only apply to SQL Server).